# Drupal - White Screen Of Death

Tags: drupal

Just changed themes with drupal and I'm left with white screen of death. Default theme which worked was Zen. This is stored under `sites/mysite.com/themes`
Theme I changed to I think is one of the themes under `themes/`
Don't have access to the database. Have FTP access. 
Is there any way to change themes or install one that will work?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? Also, if you have access to the FTP and therefore the database (`sites/default/settings.php`) you could upload something like PHPMyAdmin to clear the cache tables?

Comment: Where are error logs located? Have no access to DB at this moment. There is a settings.php file under sites/mysite.com/themes but there is no default folder. Thinking if I upload phpmyadmin how do I access Drupal tables?

Comment: The logs are server specific so I can't tell you that unfortunately. settings.php contains the database connection details. You can then use those in PHPMyAdmin to open up your Drupal database and truncate all of the tables which start with `cache_`. It's possible your host already has PHPMyAdmin installed. Who're you hosted with? Also, which Drupal version are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to correct your problem is to find what's wrong.

go to index.php and add the following lines after `<?php`

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

Then post the error here.
Don't forget to comment/remove when you're done.

**EDIT:**

If I understood correctly this was what you did before going WSOD.

1. You were using Zen theme.
2. You logged into your site with administrator privileges and went to http://yoursite.com/admin
3. You went to the theme management and changed your theme to another one (henceforth refered as "theme_b")
4. When refreshed the page (or went to another page in your site) you got the WSOD.

.

If this is true then follow these steps:

***Create a blank theme.***
In order to do this, create a folder in your computer named "theme_b".

Inside create the following files:
theme_b.info, template.php, style.css and page.tpl.php

Open theme_b.info and paste this:

```
name = theme_b
description = bla
version = 1
core = 6.x
engine = phptemplate
stylesheets[all][] = style.css
```

Save.

Open page.tpl.php and paste this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <?php print $head ?>
    <title><?php print $head_title ?></title>
    <?php print $styles ?>
    <?php print $scripts ?>
</head>
<body>
<div><?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links primary-links')) ?></div>
<div><?php print theme('links', $secondary_links, array('class' => 'links secondary-links')) ?></div>
<div id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar"><?php print $left ?></div>
<div>
<?php if ($tabs): print '<div id="tabs-wrapper" class="clear-block">'; endif; ?>
<?php if ($title): print '<h2'. ($tabs ? ' class="with-tabs"' : '') .'>'. $title .'</h2>'; endif; ?>
<?php if ($tabs): print '<ul class="tabs primary">'. $tabs .'</ul></div>'; endif; ?>
<?php if ($tabs2): print '<ul class="tabs secondary">'. $tabs2 .'</ul>'; endif; ?>
<?php if ($show_messages && $messages): print $messages; endif; ?>
<?php print $help; ?>
</div>
<div>
<?php print $content; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Save.

Then upload the folder theme_a to sites/yoursite.com/themes replacing existing theme_a folder.

This should enable you to access admin section of drupal.

Comment: I've already tried to display errors but I just get a blank screen.
Have no access to website at all. Only access I have is files on my FTP server.

Comment: This should override php.ini so the error shoudl appear. Did you try my second method?

Comment: No because I don't have access to theme management or admin. Can I set the them under any files?

Comment: No, themes are set in database. So if I understand correctly, you replaced the contents of sites/default/themes/zen with the files from another theme, is that correct?

Comment: I had normal access to theme management, site configuration etc. Switched themes and got WSOD. I don't have a default folder. I have sites/mysite.com/themes and a themes folder in root. I've uploaded a different theme into sites/mysite.com/themes and renamed it to zen but still get blank screen. Am I on the right track or way off there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5216/discussion-between-tivie-and-en-motion)

Comment: Cheers for Edit. Yeah that's what has happened to me. 
OK - I created theme_b folder, put in 4 files you said , 2 are blank style.css and template.php. I uploaded to renamed to zen. I still get blank screen. I've also tried as folder named theme_b but also blank. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You won't necessarily see any errors. For me it was a caching issue which stopped the page from loading the right content.

I cleared the cache by inserting the following on the last line of my index.php file (in Drupal root). This solved the issue for me:

```
db_query("DELETE FROM {cache};");
```

Remember to remove the line again afterwards.

More information about caching, look here: https://drupal.org/node/42055

Comment: After doing the above, then navigating to the url http://www.mywebsite.com/?q=user , I was able to see my screens again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably a PHP silent death because there's not enough memory allocated to scripts in /etc/php.ini

On shared hosting environments, you MAY be able to override this using a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You more than likely have a PHP error that isn't being shown because error reporting is turned off by default on your host. The easiest way to remedy this is to add the following code at the top of index.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Additionally, you definitely want to locate your php error logs and see if there is any additional information regarding the error there.

Checkout the Drupal help page for this topic: http://drupal.org/node/158043