# How to debug a white screen of death (WSOD) in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I created a website using Drupal months ago and I handed it down to someone and he told me that the website has been disappeared. So it happens to be Drupal's white screen of death. I followed the instructions about dealing with a [white screen of death](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54239/white-screen-of-death) in Drupal. Unfortunately, the site still won't load.

Here is the "log" after I followed the first answer (I increased the size as well).

```
Starting loading system
Finished loading system
Starting loading system
Finished loading system
Starting loading views_ui
Finished loading views_ui
Starting loading ctools
Finished loading ctools
Starting loading dblog
Finished loading dblog
Starting loading locale
Finished loading locale
Starting loading system
Starting loading block
Finished loading block
Starting loading node
Finished loading node
Starting loading shortcut
Finished loading shortcut
Starting loading system
Finished loading system
Starting loading taxonomy
Finished loading taxonomy
Starting loading translation
Finished loading translation
Starting loading user
Finished loading user
Finished loading system
Starting loading update
Finished loading update
Starting loading comment
Finished loading comment
Starting loading translation
Finished loading translation
Starting loading forum
Finished loading forum
Starting loading comment
Finished loading comment
Starting loading translation
Finished loading translation
Starting loading forum
Finished loading forum
Starting loading contextual
Finished loading contextual
Starting loading field_ui
Finished loading field_ui
Starting loading file
Finished loading file
Starting loading filter
Finished loading filter
Starting loading system
Finished loading system
Starting loading user
Finished loading user
Starting loading dashboard
Finished loading dashboard
Starting loading comment
Finished loading comment
Starting loading dashboard
Finished loading dashboard
Starting loading node
Finished loading node
Starting loading search
Finished loading search
Starting loading views
Finished loading views
Starting loading node
Finished loading node
Starting loading user
Finished loading user
Starting loading views
Finished loading views
Starting loading node
Finished loading node
Starting loading user
Finished loading user
Starting loading views
Finished loading views
Starting loading node
Finished loading node
Starting loading user
Finished loading user
Starting loading views
Finished loading views
```

All that started loading are finished.

I don't know what the problem is. Therefor I am looking for other ways to find out what is going on.

Comment: Might give this a try... it's helped me in the past : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219947/drupal-white-screen-of-death?rq=1 -- by that I mean turn on the error reporting.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! It says `Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_views_set_timezone()` what does that even mean?

Comment: Oh never mind. I just deleted the line that causes the error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Drupal - White Screen Of Death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219947/drupal-white-screen-of-death) for more options to find out what is wrong, by turning on **Error reporting**.

That might produce additional **error messages** that could help for better understanding what is going on. It will most likely also include some message(s) that will be like an indicator to what actually causes the WSOD.

Locate the line(s) in the code (module) that causes the error and temporary comment out (or delete) that line and check if the WSOD has been resolved. If so investigate what your options are for either removing these lines permanently, or preventing the errors they lead to.